# Using a verb twice to describe a chain of action

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, sentence-patterns

Is the following sentence grammatically correct:

> Cats bother dogs bother ducks.

I want to say that cats bother dogs and, also, that dogs bother ducks. Is this a correct way to do so?

If it is, can this pattern be repeated indefinitely? E.g.

> Noun1 Verb1 Noun2 Verb2 Noun3 Verb3...

Which means that “Noun1 Verb1 Noun2” and “Noun2 Verb2 Noun3” and “Noun3 Verb3 Noun4” and so on...

Comment: It's not strictly "legal" syntax, though it's generally understood in the proper context.

Comment: You can say that if you're trying to be clever and want the world to know it.  But when speaking plainly you'd do better to remember that English isn't math that can be summed up as a = b = c without having to explain yourself.

Comment: That kind of construction is so nonstandard as to be considered wrong. If you want to chain verbs together like that, you should really use pronouns. (In other words, add a *who* after *dogs*.)

Comment: No. It is not correct.

Comment: Cats **that** bother dogs bother ducks.

Comment: Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo. More capitals required next (and the x 5 version is ridiculously redundant).  // But here, comments 2 - 4 above hit the mark; 1 soft-pedals.

Comment: However "Cats bother dogs ducks bother" is fine. Or if you're very determined, "Cats swans bother bother dogs ducks bother".

Answer (score 1):

This is not standard syntax. However, it may work in a playful context, such as a poem or an aphorism.